Set attribute by comparing another attribute in different layers (QGIS)
I have two Layers.
I want the Attribute 'LABEL' of Layer 2 in a new Field called 'Label_new' in Layer 1. Both Layers have a Field called 'OBJ_REF' which contains the same number. So my plan was to compare the 'OBJ_REF' and then write the 'LABEL' into 'Label_new'.
So far I have the get_feature( 'WIS_ELE_ELET_PW2_KABEL_80a9eb68_2ce4_43c5_87cb_2469482b91af',  'OBJ_REF' ,  'OBJ_REF' ) but how can I get the Value of the 'LABEL'-Attribute?

PS: I don't even dare to try the Virtual Layers because I have zero experience with SQL.

If creating a new layer is an option, I suggest you use the join attributes table-tool (aka "join attributes by id/value").

My suggestion would be to perform a table join first, using the 'OBJ_REF' field as the common field between tables for each layer. If you haven't used table joins before, open the layer properties for Layer 1, go to the 'Joins' tab, and create a new join. Once you've done that, all the attributes of Layer 2 will be added to the attribute table of Layer 1 (matched by OBJ_REF). Once you've got that, it's a simple field calculation on the "Label_new" field using nothing more than "LABEL" as the expression. That will set the "Label_new" field to the "LABEL" field values.
So, two step summary:

Join Layer 2 to Layer 1 using the OBJ_REF field as the common field.
Open the field calculator on the joined layer, select the "Label_new" field as the field to be calculated, and use "LABEL" as your expression.

No SQL required! Give that a shot and see how that works for you!
